# While exits before it should

Tags: matlab

It's a simple problem I am having, but a little hard to explain.

I have a while loop that looks like this;

(Not the actual code)

```
x = [1;2;3;4]

while size(x(:,1),1) > 1  
    %Do stuff

    %When a condition is met move it to the bottom to be processed last
    %In this case "2"
    x = [x; x(2,:)];

    %Remove the original line for two
    x(2,:) = [];
end
```

However it exits on the third iteration instead of the fourth missing the last row.

My theory is, the  original size of x is 4 going into the while loop. By adding a row and deleting another matlab thinks that the variable is now size == 3 and exits when 3 variables are removed.

It doesn't make much sense to me. The code is confidential so I can't share the actual code, but if necessary I could attempt to replicate the error with code I can share.

I'm hoping someone has a magical answer.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a loop that reproduces your problem. The snippet you show here enters an infinite loop.

Comment: have you tried debugging the code and see what actually happens to `x`?

Comment: @shai Yes it grows and shrinks as expected.

Comment: @Schorsch I will give it a shot, but the code previous to this is involved. I know that 90% of the time its some other code that is causing the problem, but I guess I am trying to rule out a known issue with the while not being able to detect if the variable gets added to and removed from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, sorry to bug everyone.  It needs to be a >= 1 then it will also process the last item in the list. The example code, while it was an infinite loop, would never process the last item in the list.